# Pyspark union column values from string separate with comma into array

Tags: pyspark

I have a pyspark request to union multiple dataframes on id. Each dataframe has a certain column with comma separate strings.i.e.

```
df1=[("1", "a,b,c,"),
     ("2", "i,j,k"),
     ("3", "x,y,z")]
df2=[("1", "b,d,e"),
     ("2", "l,m,n"),
     ("3", "x")]
```

Now I want to union this column's value of each entry together.i.e.

```
df3=[("1", "a,b,c,d,e"),
     ("2", "i,j,k,l,m,n"),
     ("3", "x,y,z")]
```

is there a function to do that?

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is the `array_union` function.

```
data1 = [
    ('1', 'a,b,c'),
    ('2', 'i,j,k'),
    ('3', 'x,y,z')
]
data2 = [
    ('1', 'b,d,e'),
    ('2', 'l,m,n'),
    ('3', 'x')
]
df1 = spark.createDataFrame(data1, ['id', 'values1'])
df2 = spark.createDataFrame(data2, ['id', 'values2'])
df = df1.join(df2, 'id') \
    .select('id',
            F.array_join(F.array_union(F.split('values1', ','), F.split('values2', ',')), ',').alias('values'))
df.show(truncate=False)
```